# Import csv file data to populate a Prolog knowledge base

Tags: csv, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a csv file `example.csv` which contains two columns with header var1 and var2.

[image]

I want to populate an initially empty Prolog knowledge base file `import.pl` with repeated facts, while each row of `example.csv` is treated same:

```
fact(A1, A2).
fact(B1, B2).
fact(C1, C2).
```

How can I code this in SWI-Prolog ?

**EDIT, based on answer from @Shevliaskovic**:

```
:- use_module(library(csv)).
import:-
    csv_read_file('example.csv', Data, [functor(fact), separator(0';)]),
    maplist(assert, Data).
```

When `import.` is run in console, we update the knowledge base exactly the way it is requested (except for the fact that the knowledge base is directly updated in memory, rather than doing this via a file and subsequent consult).

Check `setof([X, Y], fact(X,Y), Z).` :

```
Z = [['A1', 'A2'], ['B1', 'B2'], ['C1', 'C2'], [var1, var2]].
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SWI Prolog has a built in process for this.

It is

```
csv_read_file(+File, -Rows)
```

Or you can add some options:

```
csv_read_file(+File, -Rows, +Options)
```

You can see it at the [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/csv.pl). For more information

Here is the example that the documentation has:

> Suppose we want to create a predicate table/6 from a CSV file that we
>   know contains 6 fields per record. This can be done using the code
>   below. Without the option arity(6), this would generate a predicate
>   table/N, where N is the number of fields per record in the data.

```
?- csv_read_file(File, Rows, [functor(table), arity(6)]),
   maplist(assert, Rows).
```

**For example:**

If you have a File.csv that looks like:

```
A1  A2
B1  B2
C1  C2
```

You can import it to SWI like:

```
9 ?- csv_read_file('File.csv', Data).
```

The result would be:

```
Data = [row('A1', 'A2'), row('B1', 'B2'), row('C1', 'C2')].
```

Comment: Thx, I am quite new to Prolog. I am struggling with your advise. The question is how to convert the specific csv file's content to a new knowledge base file, which is then ready to be consulted.

Comment: @user2030503 I added an example. Does that help you?

Comment: Almost, how can I convert the Data into facts in the knowledge base file?

Comment: Thanks @Shevliaskovic after some further digging seems I could build on your answer to find a solution (made the EDIT in my post). Prolog is a great language and the community too - THANKS!

Comment: Documentation link is broken, I think this is the working link http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=csv_read_file/3

Comment: @user2030503 Can you elaborate how you get it to work?