# Read a CSV file in prolog and format the data into predicates of the form: prefers(employer 1, [Student1, Student2, Student3])

Tags: csv, prolog

I have been trying to figure this out for days now. I have a two csv files. One with the names of employers and students in order of the employer's preferences. The other with the names of students and the employers they wish to work form, again in order of preference. The files look like this:

```
Thales,  Melissa, Craig,   Luke
US Post, Craig,   Luke,    Melissa
IBM,     Luke,    Melissa, Craig
```

and

```
Melissa, Thales,  US Post, IBM
Craig,   IBM,     Thales,  US Post
Luke,    US Post, IBM,     Thale
```

I need to read this file line by line and populate a prolog database with the predicates like:

```
prefers(Thales, [Melissa, Craig, Luke]). 
prefers(Craig,  [IBM, Thales, US Post]).

student(Melissa).
employer(IBM).
```

I know how to open the file, read it, and create a stream, but I have no clue how to do what I asked for in this question. The solution is most likely DCG based.

Comment: _I have been trying to figure this out for days now._ That affirmation is highly dubious but check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095068/import-csv-file-data-to-populate-a-prolog-knowledge-base wherein a predicate is used that can read CSV directly.